# Не выполняется запрос jdbc mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Вот мне нужно создать нового пользователя и логин и пароль необходимо эти данные подставить из тестовых полей в запрос но он не работает, в чем ошибка?

```
 connection.updateQuery(String.format("CREATE USER '%s'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '%s'",login.getText(),password.getText()));
 connection.updateQuery(String.format("CREAGRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '%s'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION",login.getText()));
```

В результате полчаю ошибку `UnknownFormatConversionException`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ''' at
java.base/java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2730) at 
java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2706) at 
java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2653) at 
java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2607) at 
java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2734) at     
com.testing.Home_form$2.actionPerformed(Home_form.java:68) at
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? См. [mcve]

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2730)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2706)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2653)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2607)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2734)
 at com.testing.Home_form$2.actionPerformed(Home_form.java:68)
 at

Comment: Попробуйте использовать конкатенацию:
`"CREATE USER \'" + login.getText() + "\'@\'" + password.getText() + "\' IDENTIFIED BY"...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемма не в подключении, а в форматировании строки. 
Если точнее в позиции `'%'` - в данной реализации знак `%` является специальньм символом. Чтоб его использовать, следует просто продублировать его:

```
("CREATE USER '%s'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY '%s'",login.getText(),password.getText()));
 connection.updateQuery(String.format("CREAGRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '%s'@'%%' WITH GRANT OPTION",login.getText()));
```